# Bound on arguments in Gegenabuer polynomial expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

In Higher Transcendental Functions Volume I (available here:[https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43491/}](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43491/%7D)), equation (1) of section 3.15.1 gives the following expansion for the so-called Gegenbauer polynomials
\begin{equation}
(1-2hz+h^2)^{-\nu} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n^{\nu}(z)h^n, \qquad |h| < |z\pm(z^2-1)^{1/2}|,
\end{equation}
where $C_n^{\nu}(z)$ is the Gegenabuer polynomial with complex argument $z$. There is some details on where this expansion comes from under the statement, however I don't understand where the $|h| < |z\pm(z^2-1)^{1/2}|$ comes from. I have seen in other texts that the expansion is true for $|h| < 1$ but never the bound given in this book. I was wondering if anyone could explain it? I should note that $h$ can be complex too.

Comment: This is from complex analysis. The Taylor expansion converges up to the closest singularity from the center. For a fixed $z$, the right is the Taylor expansion around $h=0$ of the left. The left is singular at the zeros (in $h$ for a fixed $z$) of $1+2hz+h^2$. Those are the $z\pm\sqrt{z^2-1}$. The distance from these to $0$ are $|z\pm\sqrt{z^2-1}|$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could I ask, how do you know the right-hand side is a Taylor expansion? The $C_n^{\nu}(z)$ term isn't the traditional coefficient term for a Taylor series.

Comment: The $C_n^\nu(z)$ are the Taylor coefficients. And if you were to find some over series of powers of $h$ converging to the same function on a neighborhood of $h=0$, the coefficients would be the same. That's is the uniqueness of power series representation.

Comment: So you are saying that the right-hand side is a power series representation of the left-hand side with the coefficients being the Gegenbauer polynomials. The radius of convergence is the distance to the nearest pole which is the $z \pm \sqrt{z^2+1}$ and so $h$ needs to bounded in that way. Moreover, this power series representation is unique as there is only one power series available for each function. Do I have all that correct?